# How many components can be cached using Vue keep-alive?

Tags: caching, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, keep-alive

I'm using `keep-alive` in `the router-view` like this:

```
<keep-alive>
  <router-view></router-view>
<keep-alive>
```

So I'm saving all "pages" of my app. My questions:

- How many components can keep-alive save?
- Can I program something to make keep-alive save just one component (the last one)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661595/how-to-destroy-a-vuejs-component-that-is-being-cached-by-keep-alive
It looks like you can use the [include option on keep-alive](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive) to be dynamic array (`v-bind:include="[ 'dashboard' ]` in the example). So you could try and keep only the name of the last loaded component in that array

Comment: Hello @zizzo thanks for the response. I did see it, but I could not think how I can use this logic to destroy the current keep-alive and save the next one :/ I don't know the current component that is keeped alive and neither the next one. Do you know how I can do it?

Comment: I have never tried, but I guess you could use a [navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html), and before the new components gets loaded (because user wants to browse a new page) you can save the name of current component in the keep-alive's include array and remove the previous one, so that the `v-bind:include="componentsArray"` will always only have one component.

Comment: @zizzo It's a pretty good ideia. I'll try it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem using the sugestion of @zizzo. I saved in the vuex the component that I wanted to save when I want to save (the last one). The code stayed like this:

```
<keep-alive :include="[componentToKeepAlive.name]">
  <router-view></router-view>
<keep-alive>


...mapGetters({
  componentToKeepAlive: 'global/componentToKeepAlive'
})
```