# How can I destroy a cached Vue component from keep-alive?

Tags: vue.js

My Vue app has a dynamic tabs mechanism.

Users can create as many tabs as the want on the fly, each tab having its own state (eg "Pages").

I am using the `<keep-alive>` component to cache the different pages.

```
<keep-alive include="page">
  <router-view :key="$route.params.id" />
</keep-alive>
```

But users can also "close" individual tab. As pages tend to store a lot of datas, I would like to delete the according page component from the cache, *as the user close the tab*.

How can I programmatically destroy a cached component inside keep-alive ?

Comment: Maybe you need to take a look this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661595/how-to-destroy-a-vuejs-component-that-is-being-cached-by-keep-alive

Comment: @SIMDD this technique will destroy all cached pages as you remove the keep alive component totally with v-if. I want to destroy a single one cached component.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can call `this.$destroy()` before user close the tab and delete all of data and event binding in that one.

Comment: should not use just `this.$destory()` in cached components.  this will occur side effect

Comment: I found this will cause the component unable to be cached forever, not sure if it is related to the UI framework I use.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind losing the state when a tab is added/removed, then you can try these:

- Use v-if and turn off the keep-alive component and turn it back on in
  nextTick
- Use v-bind on the include list, and remove "page" and add it
  back in nextTick

Comment: I want to keep the state of all other pages ! Doing so I will loose all page's states.

Comment: The whole point of using KeepAlive is usually caching state

Answer (score 3):

```
<keep-alive :include="cachedViews">
  <router-view :key="key" />
</keep-alive>
```

cachedViews is the array of the route component name

First when create a tab, cachedViews push the cached route name, when you switch the opened tab, the current route is cached.

Second when close the tab, cachedViews pop the cached route name, the route
component will destroyed.

Comment: Doesn't work for multiple routes with same component name. Eg, I want to cache page/1 and page/2 and I want to destroy only page/2.

Answer (score 2):

based on the answer of **@feasin**, here is the setup I am using

*template*

```
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <keep-alive :include="cachedViews">
      <component :is="Component" :key="$route.fullPath" />
    </keep-alive>
  </router-view>
```

*script*

```
import { ref, inject, watch } from "vue";

export default {
  components: { CustomRouterLink },
  setup() {
    const cachedViewsDefault = ["Page1", "Page1", "Page3"];
    var cachedViews = ref([]);

    const auth = inject("auth");

    // check whether user is logged in (REACTIVE!)
    const isSignedIn = auth.isSignedIn;

    // set the initial cache state
    if (isSignedIn.value) {
      cachedViews.value = cachedViewsDefault;
    }

    // clear the cache state
    watch(isSignedIn, () => {
      if (!isSignedIn.value) {
        cachedViews.value = [];
      } else {
        cachedViews.value = cachedViewsDefault;
      }
    });

    return {
      cachedViews,
    };
  },
};
```

First I set the initial cached views value based on whether the user is logged in or not.. After the user logs-out I simply set the array value to an empty array.
When the user logs back in - I push the default array keys back into the array.

This example of course does not provide the login/logout functionality, it is only meant as a POC to to the solution proposed by the **@feasin** (which seems like a good approach to me)

**Edit 19.01.2022**

I now understand the shortcomings of such approach. It does not allow to gradually destroy a certain component. Given that we have a component named `Item` and it's path is `Item/{id}` - there is currently no native way (in `Vuejs3`) to remove, let's say a cached `item` with `Id = 2`. Follow up on this issue on the `Github`: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/283

**Edit 20-21.01.2022**

Note that you have to use the `computed` function for inclusion list. Otherwise the component will not ever be `unmounted`.

Here is the fiddle with the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/7f2d4c0t/4/

Here's fiddle with the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/mvj2z3pL/

```
return {
    cachedViews: computed(() => Array.from(cachedViews.value)),
}
```

Comment: Hello Alex, Edit 19.01.2022 this problem, now have a good solution? If so? Can you update the answer? Thank you so much for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function in `keep-alive` which allows you to clear a specific component from the cache.

However, you can clear the cache from the VNode directly inside the component you want to destroy by calling this function :

```js
import Vue, { VNode } from 'vue'

interface KeepAlive extends Vue {
  cache: { [key: string]: VNode }
  keys: string[]
}

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'PageToDestroy',
  ...
  methods: {
    // Make sure you are not on this page anymore before calling it
    clearPageFromKeepAlive() {
      const myKey = this.$vnode.key as string
      const keepAlive = this.$vnode.parent?.componentInstance as KeepAlive

      delete keepAlive.cache[myKey]
      keepAlive.keys = keepAlive.keys.filter((k) => k !== myKey)

      this.$destroy()
    }
  },
})
```

For me, it doesn't cause any memory leaks and the component is not in the Vue.js devtools anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solutions provided by [@feasin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68465599/10667502) and [@Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70605559/10667502), I've implemented a method to clear cached views. Below is the approach that I've taken:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <RouterView v-slot="{ Component }">
      <KeepAlive :include="whitelistedViews">
        <component :is="Component" />
      </KeepAlive>
    </RouterView>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, nextTick } from "vue"

// Initialize whitelistedViews with a ref holding an undefined value
// This will initially allow all views to be cached.
const whitelistedViews = ref<string[]>()  // Ref<string[] | undefined>

// Function to clear cached views
async function clearCachedViews() {
  // First, set the value to an empty array to clear all current caches
  whitelistedViews.value = []

  // Wait for the next DOM update cycle to ensure the cache is cleared
  await nextTick()

  // Finally, reset whitelistedViews to undefined to allow all views to be cached again
  whitelistedViews.value = undefined
}
</script>
```

You can also use [provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) to share the `clearCachedViews` function with child components.

Answer (score 0):

For `vue3` + vite

Patch the [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/runtime-core/src/components/KeepAlive.ts#L202) with `vite.config.ts`

```js
function patchVueKeepAlive() {
    let replaced = false
    return {
        name: 'patch-vue-keep-alive',
        // https://cn.rollupjs.org/plugin-development/#transform
        transform(code, id) {
            if (!replaced && id.includes('/node_modules/')) {
                // make the function accessable from outside
                code = code.replace(/function pruneCacheEntry\(key\) (\{\s+const cached = cache\.get\(key\);.+?keys.delete\(key\);\s+})/s, (...ms) => {
                    replaced = true
                    return 'var pruneCacheEntry = sharedContext.prune = function(key)' + ms[1]
                })
                if (replaced) {
                    console.log('Keep-Alive Hacked!')
                    return {code, map: null}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


const viteConfig = defineConfig((mode: ConfigEnv) => {
    return {
        plugins: [patchVueKeepAlive(), /* ... */ ],
    }
}
```

```bash
npm/yarn dev --force
```

Now `prune()` on keep-alive `ref` is usable

```html
<keep-alive ref="KeepAlive">
    <component :is="Component" :key="reloadKey" />
</keep-alive>
```

```
const KeepAlive = ref()

router.afterEach(() => {
    let key
    while (key = pruneQueue.pop()) {
        console.log('prune', key)
        try {
            KeepAlive.value.prune(key)
        } catch (e: any) {
            // cache not exists
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
    // show all the caches
    console.log(KeepAlive.value.$.__v_cache)
})

const pruneQueue: string[] = []

function pruneCache(key: string) {
    pruneQueue.push(key)
}
```