# Vue3 force reset/clear of keep-alive components

Tags: state, vuejs3, keep-alive

I'm using keep-alive to maintain the state of a multi-step form in Vue3 so users can navigate back and forth as needed.

What I can't figure out, is how to force a clear of the cache. When users complete the form I give them an option to re-start and I currently clear the form submission object and return the users to page 1 of the form but keep-alive is preserving the form state so checkboxes are pre-selected. Is there a call I can make from my reset function to clear the keep-alive cache? Ideally for only some of the form steps, not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up using an entirely different method and thought I would put it here in case it is of use to someone else.

I found it here: https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Basically, a reset of a component can be forced by changing its key value. This has the added benefit of letting you selectively force a re-render of any number of child components.

In the parent.

```js
<PageOne :key="page_one_key">

<script>
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      page_one_key: 0,
  }
  },
  ...
  methods: {
   myreset(){
     this.page_one_key += 1;
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

If there are downsides to this approach I would love to know but it seems to work perfectly - allows back/forwards navigation of my form and selective resetting of the cached components.

It is also simple to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to do.;) There's no built-in method to clear the keepAlive cache.

Looks like the form is not completely reseted but maybe could be enough to destroy the instance of components wrapped in

Are you using `key="x"` on the component that's wrapped with ? Like:

```js
<KeepAlive>
   <component key="x"/>
</KeepAlive >
```

reseting the key together with redirecting to 1st page could help.
But also to my mind came an idea that You maybe should re-initialize form initialData
ex:

```js
<script>
const initialState = () => {
  return {
    name: '',
    surename: '',
    location: {
      name: null,
    },
  };
};

export default {
  data() {
    return initialState();
  },

  methods: {
    reset() {
      Object.assign(this.$data, initialState());
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

let's dive into

https://learnvue.co/tutorials/vue-keep-alive

---

#### Found related issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71766767/10900851
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6259#issuecomment-436209870

Comment: I just ended up manually resetting all the checkboxes in the component to false. Your solution does seem more thorough though. More cache management would be helpful; I have basically had to implement state management independently of vue to handle a form reset and back button on a wizard... which can't be ideal.